# When creating a Svelte app from scratch, I can't find a "./public" folder after a build

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Context : I wanted to try out the framework Svelte.js on a simple example.

When creating an Svelte app from scratch using:

```
npm create svelte@latest myapp
```

I can't find a `./public` folder after a build.
(The build operations used the command: `npm run build`  )

Instead, the build command seems to put the generated javaScript files in a hidden folder:

```
.svelte-kit
```

However, I don't see a folder in there with an index.html file and a matching app.js file.

- Did I miss something?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- Should I have provided extra options to the build command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SvelteKit produces a `.svelte-kit` directory during the build by default, so you have not done anything wrong.

If you are building a fully static site you can use the [static adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters#supported-environments-static-sites) to generate a `build` directory with nothing but static files, if that was what you were expecting.

Comment: for completeness : https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static

Comment: To start form a preconfigured skeleton app: `npx degit sveltejs/template app2`